# Why does notifyAll() not resume the other threads in this simple case?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm new to Java concurrency. I have a simple object with 3 methods, each corresponding to code run by 3 different threads. Why does the notifyAll() statement in this case not release the wait in the other two threads?

```
public class Main {
static class Obj {
      synchronized void t1 () {
          System.out.println("T1 ran");
          try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          notifyAll();
      }
     synchronized void t2 () {
         try {
             wait();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         System.out.println("T2 ran");
     }
    synchronized void t3() {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("T3 ran");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Obj o = new Obj();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            o.t1();
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            o.t2();
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            o.t3();
        }
    }).start();
}}
```

I expected:
T1 ran
~~pause for 1 second~~
T2 ran
T3 ran

I got:
T1 ran

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Thread.sleep` does not release or relax any locks in the way that `wait` does, so the synchronization is still in full effect and the other threads won't be allowed to enter their methods during the sleep.

If you replace the

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

with

```
wait(1000);
```

the other threads will be allowed capture the same lock, enter the methods, start waiting, and the sample will work as you expected.

Comment: @that other guy: I just tested the source with 3 different "Objects" containing the method `t1,t2,t3` (Obj1, Obj2, Obj3) - outcome was the same. Why is a synchronized method on `Obj1` preventing different threads to access `Obj2.t2` respectively `Obj3.t3` ?

Comment: Ah never mind - Other methods have been enetered, but ofc. `notifyAll` has no impact then :-) So the other objects threads are waiting until dawn :)

Comment: Methods t2 and t3 will only enter after t1 has finished. This is because once a thread enters a synchronised method it will lock the entire object (so the two t2 and t3 are synchronised too so can't be accessed at the same time). And as said sleep() will not release the lock as opposed to wait().

Answer (score 3):

Your three methods are `synchronized` on the same instance. And `Thread#sleep(..)` does not release the lock acquired by `synchronized`. So the thread executing `t1` acquires the lock, sleeps for a second, wakes up, calls `notifyAll()` and completes.

Your two other threads then each get a turn at executing and call `wait()`. But there's nothing left to notify them, so your application blocks.

You've got a race condition. Change the order in which you start the threads or run it like you have enough times and you'll potentially see different behavior.

Comment: Did I not account for that by making t1 sleep for 1 second?

Comment: @db-user I'll review. Missed that.

Comment: @db-user `sleep` doesn't release the `synchronized` lock. All threads are going to wait until that method invocation completes.

Answer (score 3):

If I am correct, the threads for method t2 and t3 cannot enter the method, as thread t1 is locking the object for the whole time as is it a synchronized method. And by the time t2 and t3 actually run the notifyAll() already happened, so they wait forever :(

You should try starting t2 and t3 first, then t1.

As already pointed out. Thread.sleep() does not release any locks or monitors so the method cannot be entered by other threads as it is marked synchronized: [Thread.sleep()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long))